# How to use np.savetext to convert a pandas dataframe and save to csv?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm using:

```
df.to_csv('flename.csv', index=False)
```

to save dataframe to csv file,but while save a large size file,it is very slow.So I tried to first convert the dataframe into numpy and then use :

```
np.savetxt('filename.csv',df.to_numpy())
```

Then I received error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1424, in savetxt
    v = format % tuple(row) + newline
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `savetxt`?  Or just assumed that because you can use `to_csv` without much thought, you can do the same with `savetxt`?  The default `fmt='%.18e'`.  `savetxt` is a rather simple file writer, using standard python `%` string formatting.  `to_csv` has a lot more information at hand to use in formatting.  Just take a look at the `to_numpy()` array.

Comment: I can guess what's wrong with the `df`, but in question like this you really should describe it (header at least), and show a portion of the `df.to_numpy()`.  Put some work into writing a good question.

Comment: I should add that `savetxt` writes an array in a csv format.  It does not `convert` anything, much less a dataframe.